# Ubuntu dual boot - only one has internet connection

Tags: 14.04, internet

I have Ubuntu 12.04.02 and have working internet connection:

[image]

Then I have install among the 12.04 the new 14.04. Unfortunately I am not able to connect to the internet - it is always loading.

Could anyone tell what is causing that?

---

I guess some driver is missing because if I connect the Ethernet cable to other PC it is working. But how can I debug what I need and downloaded as I have not got network on the 14.04?

Comment: post `sudo lshw -c network` and `ifconfig -a` from 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the issue installing the following driver the [LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).